# split dynamic number of entries dynamically between 2 columns

Tags: dynamic

I have a list of dynamic entries I want to split evenly between two columns. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery. Something like this maybe: http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2012/jquery/how-to-split-a-dynamic-list-into-two-equal-columns-using-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Splitter](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/splitter), I've used it before for tis purpose.

Comment: +1 for Splitter. Works as advertised, no muss no fuss.

Answer (score 1):

If they have to be in absolutely two columns, you can make two channel entries calls and use the expressionengine modulus (%) operator

```
<section class="column1">
{exp:channel:entries channel="foo"}
    {if count % 2 == 0}
        {title}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
</section>
<section class="column2">
{exp:channel:entries channel="foo"}
    {if count % 2 == 1}
        {title}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
</section>
```

But that means that you are doubling your queries. I would suggest trying an alternate html/css layout that allows you to make a single channel entries call.